# Save a file from a web request

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to convert an old Perl script into an SSIS package that amongst other things gets a zip file from a website.  The URL of the site is a JSP page that takes a number of values in the querystring.  Putting the URL into a browser causes the page to automatically download the file, no user interaction required.

I've spent hours trying to replicate this in SSIS with no luck!  I've tried the WebClient class, including the OpenRead, UploadValues and DownloadFile methods with various combinations of QueryString's, or NameValueCollection's.  The end result is always "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work??

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you'll get a better response if you actually post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly modified C# script I found (probably on here) in SSIS to do this.  If someone recognizes this code, I will be happy to withdraw this answer.

Now, **I am not a C# developer**, so if this code is horrific I plead ignorance.  It does download a file from a website, however, which is all I needed it to do.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;



public void Main()
        {
            //Init Variables
            string downloadurl = Dts.Variables["User::downloadlink"].Value.ToString();
            string targetdir = Dts.Variables["User::targetdir"].Value.ToString();
            string targetfile = Dts.Variables["User::targetfilename"].Value.ToString();
            bool fileexists = File.Exists(targetdir + targetfile);
            bool overwrite = Convert.ToBoolean(Dts.Variables["User::overwritedlfile"].Value);
            string webpassword = "";
            string weblogin = "";
        try
        {



            // Logging start of download
            bool fireAgain = true;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Start downloading " + Dts.Variables["User::downloadlink"].Value.ToString(), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // For authenticated downloads

            if ((webpassword != "" || weblogin != "") && (fileexists == false || (overwrite == true && fileexists == true)))
            {
                weblogin = Dts.Variables["User::weblogin"].Value.ToString();
                webpassword = Dts.Variables["User::webpassword"].Value.ToString();
                // Create a webclient to download a file
                using (WebClient mySSISWebClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    //Insert credentials
                    mySSISWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(weblogin, webpassword);
                    //Download file (source, destination)
                    mySSISWebClient.DownloadFile(downloadurl, targetdir + targetfile);
                }

                //// Logging end of download
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Finished downloading " + Dts.Variables["User::downloadlink"].Value.ToString(), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
                //Console.WriteLine("Download Complete");


                // Quit Script Task succesful
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            // For regular downloads
            if (fileexists == false || (overwrite == true && fileexists == true))
            {

                // Create a webclient to download a file
                using (WebClient mySSISWebClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    mySSISWebClient.DownloadFile(downloadurl, targetdir + targetfile);
                }

                //// Logging end of download
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Finished downloading " + Dts.Variables["User::downloadlink"].Value.ToString(), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
                //Console.WriteLine("Download Complete");


                // Quit Script Task succesful
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            else
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", "Download failed: " + (targetfile + " already exists in the target directory"), string.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                throw new Exception(targetfile + " already exists in the target directory");


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging why download failed
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", "Download failed: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

            //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
```

Comment: Same result :(, "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".

Comment: Does the URL have two colons (:) in it?